# Get data from current parse user to post in another class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

EDIT: figured it out, was user error.

I want to get data from current user and post it into another className. Code is below. Everything is working except
post["postcategory"] = PFUser.currentUser()!["lastviewed"] as? String
The post doesnt add ["lastviewed"] as? String

Whole code:

```
var post = PFObject(className: "Post")
post["message"] = singlecomparecomment.text
post["userId"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!
post["postcategory"] = PFUser.currentUser()!["lastviewed"] as? String
post.saveInBackground
```

Comment: What's the error message saying?

Comment: it builds but when i press the button taht runs the command, it get a "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)" on that line. I get Break on warnParseOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Comment: Break on warnParseOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: okay i figured it out, in parse it was actually "lasviewed" but it is still not posting. the post goes through but doesnt add post["postcategory"] = PFUser.currentUser()!["lastviewed"] as? String

Comment: So there was just a typo? )) Glad you figured it yourself... I guess you can answer and accept that so others can see and reflect in the future.

Comment: okay its completely working now, thanks for the responses. i feel hopeless without people like u on stackoverflow.